# Video as div background in pure css and html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I updated my question and code here so it hopefully makes more sense. Essentially, I need to replace the .video div (with the image) to a video instead of an image. I need to keep to blue overlay and everything else but change it from an image to a video. I already tried adding

```
<video id="video" poster="C:\Users\name\Desktop\poster.JPG" autoplay muted loop>
<source src="C:\Users\name\Desktop\footage.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

but it didn't seem to work. Anything to get this working?

```html
<style>
.front {
  background-color:blue;
  height: 91vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width:100%;
}

.video {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/107/800/800) center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: -100vh;
  position: sticky;
  width:100%;
  top: 0;
}

.container {
  height:200vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="front"></div>

  <div class="video"></div>
</div>

<div style="height:150vh"> more content later </div>
```

Comment: So you want the an overlay over the video element, correct?

Comment: @Alanaj instead of a red background on the #video div i need it to be a video instead of a solid red

Comment: Try to get rid of the background color, and get rid of the z-index.

Comment: @Alanaj tried earlier, didn't seem to work

Comment: And the video doesn't show up at all?

Comment: @Alanaj no I have no idea why either

Comment: can you put a position of relative on the .container and and take it off of the overlay. Change the overlay to absolute. and change the position of the video absolute as well. The index needs of the video needs to be positive as well.

Comment: @Alanaj tried as well, didnt work. Updated my code and question to make more sense

Comment: Why do you have a poster if you just want the video?

Comment: @Alanaj its the first keyframe of the video to have loaded before the video starts

Comment: Oh, okay. Can you change the source of the video, by putting the file into your code editor or is it already in there?

Comment: @Alanaj How so?

Comment: You can just drag your mp4 file into the folder your working. If you are using VS code you can drag that file into that particular folder as well.

Comment: @Alanaj just working in codepen right now and not a program.

Comment: Oh, okay, do you think you can send me a link to the codepen?

Comment: I think I know what is wrong. You're blocking the video by putting the video container background as the url. It needs to be .video video {background: url(etc)}

Comment: @Alanaj can you paste the code thats works

Comment: you can either use an iframe to display the video. with this you can also adjust the overlay as per your needs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? We have set a *position:relative* to `.content`. and *width:100%* to `video`, and manage z-index of `video` and `overlay`.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/ge0d4ys9/

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  height:100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#myVideo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be useful. I just need the red div behind the blue one to be a video instead of the solid red color.

Comment: updated my code and question to hopefully make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this?

```html
<style>
  .front {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 91vh;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .video {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -100vh;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }

  .container {
    height: 200vh;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
  }

</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="front"></div>

  <div class="video">
    <video style='width:100%;' id="background_video" autoplay loop muted>
     <source type='video/mp4' src='https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/720/Big_Buck_Bunny_720_10s_1MB.mp4' />
    </video>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
  </div>

</div>
<div style="height:150vh"> more content later </div>
```

THIS IS THE OLD ONE LOOK ABOVE

```js
    (function() {

      var bv = new Bideo();
      bv.init({
        videoEl: document.querySelector('#background_video'),
        container: document.querySelector('.video'),
        autoplay: true,
        src: [{
          src: 'https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4',
          type: 'video/mp4'
        }],
      });
    }());
```

```html
<style>
  .front {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 91vh;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .video {
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: -100vh;
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }

  .container {
    height: 200vh;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
  }

</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="front"></div>

  <div class="video">
    <video style='width:100%;' id="background_video" loop muted></video>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
  </div>

</div>
<div style="height:150vh"> more content later </div>

<script src="https://rishabhp.github.io/bideo.js/bideo.js"></script>
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to have both the width and height take up the full screensize? right now its either the width at full and not the height or vice versa. Would need both?

Comment: I believe that depends on the aspect ratio of the video, but just try setting the video height to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick and you don't need to worry about styling or wrapping the video any further. You could also do this using flex but this way you only need to position the child `DIV` within the parent one so it's less CSS overall. Video is taken from W3 schools so there's one to play in the example.

```css
.blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.video {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">

  <div class="video">
    <video controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work with the setup I currently have. I need to red div behind the blue to display the video instead of a solid background color.

Comment: Just swap the indexes around. If your current setup doesn't work you should probably change it even if it means rewriting this section.

Comment: updated my code and question to hopefully make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.front {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.video {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1
}

// *********
.video video {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/107/800/800) height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="front"></div>

  <div class="video">
    <video autoplay controls>
      <source src="http://learn.shayhowe.com/assets/misc/courses/html-css/adding-media/earth.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      <source src="http://learn.shayhowe.com/assets/misc/courses/html-css/adding-media/earth.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Cameron Cole If it doesn't work, we'll try something else!