# HTML - Video background is only showing in Safari but not showing/working in Google Chrome

Tags: html

my code is as simple as it is, video is fine, as it is working perfectly in Safari mobile or PC, but not working in Google Chrome (in mobile or PC). It will be blank in Chrome. I had tried alternatives by using video tags but it doesn't resolve the issue, please help thank you.

```html
<section class="test-section" style="height:350px; 
background: url(https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1695475892~acl=%2Fvimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us%2F01%2F3990%2F16%2F419951337%2F1813073867.mp4~hmac=2d4f723c1f6418da935bee5e3d8b2d9bea27f888e1b3913bb5eb685f3e32d664/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/3990/16/419951337/1813073867.mp4)">Section text</section>
```

Comment: Here are working solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527200/video-as-div-background-in-pure-css-and-html#

Comment: Indeed. the snippet I made you does not work in Chrome

Comment: mp4 is not a recognised valid background except in Safari it seems